# Public com 2 variaveis não retorna valor

Tags: java, android

Tenho 3 publics que deveriam retornar um valor de cálculo para eu apresentar na tela da Activity. A primeira, `volume_agua_mehta()`, retorna normalmente, porém a segunda, `massa_brita_mehta()`, e a terceira, `agua_material_cimentício_mehta()`, retornam `NaN` na `TextView`.

Queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Obs: Todas essas publics estão na mesma classe e recuperei as variáveis certas e da forma correta.

```
public double volume_agua_mehta(){
    return resultado = 221.91 * exp((-0.005)*resistencia_concreto);
}

public double massa_brita_mehta(){
    return resultado = (130 * 5 + 0.319 * Math.log(resistencia_concreto) - 3.332)) * massa_especifica_sss_brita;
}

public double agua_material_cimentício_mehta(){
    Calculo_Mehta Calculo_Mehta = new Calculo_Mehta();

    double volume_agua_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.volume_agua_mehta();
    double massa_cimento_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.massa_cimento_mehta();
    double massa_aditivo_mineral1_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.massa_aditivo_mineral1_mehta();
    double massa_aditivo_minera2_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.massa_aditivo_minera2_mehta();

    return resultado = volume_agua_mehta/(massa_cimento_mehta+massa_aditivo_mineral1_mehta+massa_aditivo_minera2_mehta);
}
```

Na classe `Dosagem_Dados_Gerais`:

```
public EditText txt_resistencia_concreto;
public EditText txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dosagem__dados__gerais);

    txt_resistencia_concreto=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_resistencia_concreto);
    txt_massa_especifica_sss_areia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_massa_especifica_sss_areia);


    final Button btn_proximo_dados_gerais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_proximo_dados_gerais);
    btn_proximo_dados_gerais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //AQUI SÃO FEITAS VERIFICAÇÕES SE OS EDITTEXTS ESTÃO PREENCHIDOS, VOU PULAR ESSA PARTE E IR DIRETO AO PONTO

            Intent it_mehta = new Intent(Dosagem_Dados_Gerais.this, Calculo_Mehta.class);

            it_mehta.putExtra("resistencia_concreto", txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());
            it_mehta.putExtra("massa_especifica_sss_brita", txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita.getText().toString());
            startActivity(it_mehta);

        }
    }
```

Classe `Calculo_Mehta`:

```
public double resistencia_concreto;
public double massa_especifica_sss_brita;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String txt_resistencia_concreto = getIntent().getStringExtra("resistencia_concreto"); //Recuperar na string
    resistencia_concreto=Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto); //Passando para double

    String txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita= getIntent().getStringExtra("massa_especifica_sss_brita");
    massa_especifica_sss_brita=Double.parseDouble(txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita);

}
```

Depois daqui vem aquelas publics que mostrei no inicio do post.

Classe `Resultado`:

```
public TextView resultado_agua;
public TextView resultado_brita;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

    resultado_agua = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado_agua);
    resultado_brita = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado_brita);

    final Button btn_calcular_dosagem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calcular_dosagem);
    btn_calcular_dosagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        volume = Double.parseDouble(resultado_volume.getText().toString());

        public void onClick (View View) {

            Calculo_Mehta Calculo_Mehta = new Calculo_Mehta();

            //ESSE PRIMEIRO FUNCIONA E MOSTRA NO EDIT TEXT PERFEITAMENTE
            double massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.volume_agua_mehta()*volume; //Massa água
            String stg_resultado_agua_mehta = Double.toString(massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_mehta);
            resultado_agua.setText(stg_resultado_agua_mehta);

            //ESSE NÃO FUNCIONA
            double massa_brita_mehta = (Calculo_Mehta.massa_brita_mehta(Calculo_Mehta.resistencia_concreto,Calculo_Mehta.massa_especifica_sss_brita))*volume; //Massa brita
            String stg_brita_mehta_mehta = Double.toString(massa_brita_mehta);
            resultado_brita.setText(stg_brita_mehta_mehta);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as variáveis do método 'agua_material_cimentício_mehta' são preenchidas corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O segundo método não "funciona" porque utiliza os atributos `Calculo_Mehta.resistencia_concreto` e `Calculo_Mehta.massa_especifica_sss_brita`, da classe Calculo_Mehta, que só são inicializados no método `onCreate()`.

Você está a usar uma Activity como se ela fosse uma classe "normal".
Ao fazer `Calculo_Mehta Calculo_Mehta = new Calculo_Mehta();` está a criar um objecto de Calculo_Mehta mas o método `onCreate()` não é chamado.

Uma Activity deve ser sempre criada(lançada) via um Intent.

Não consigo lhe dar uma alternativa porque não entendo/conheço a estrutura da app, nem tenho a certeza do que quer fazer.

No entanto uma coisa é certa, essa forma é errada e não irá "funcionar".

Comment: entendo. Então para esse caso voce acha interessante colocar as contas no Activity de resposta mesmo? Não sei se essa pergunta é adequada, já que não apresentei aqui o layout

Comment: Aquela parte do OnCreate() que usei no Calculo_Mehta então está errada?

Comment: As "contas" podem estar onde são utilizadas ou numa classe própria, se forem utilizadas em mais de uma Activity devem estar numa classe própria. Uma Activity não deve ser instanciada para os seus métodos serem chamados por outra.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigada!!!

Answer (score 0):

Primeira dica é verificar se os valores estão sendo preenchidos corretamente. Por exemplo no seu primeiro método `volume_agua_mehta`(), confira se a variável `resistencia_concreto` está recebendo o valor desejado. Criei um método baseado no seu porém com valores fixos importando a `java.lang.Math.exp` e consigo um retorno corretamente:

```
public double volume_agua_mehta(){
   return 221.91 * exp((-0.005)*234);
}
```

Retorno:

> 68.8735

Você pode também criar um método passando um parâmetro `resistencia_concreto`. Veja:

```
public double volume_agua_mehta(double resistencia_concreto){
        return 221.91 * exp((-0.005)*resistencia_concreto);
}
```

Veja também como ficaria o método `agua_material_cimentício_mehta()` passando como parâmetro a classe `Calculo_Mehta`:

```
public double agua_material_cimenticio_mehta(Calculo_Mehta Calculo_Mehta) {
    return Calculo_Mehta.volume_agua_mehta() / (Calculo_Mehta.massa_cimento_mehta() 
            + Calculo_Mehta.massa_aditivo_mineral1_mehta() 
            + Calculo_Mehta.massa_aditivo_minera2_mehta());
}
```

Sendo assim, ao chamar o `TextView` você deve fazer desta forma:

```
Calculo_Mehta cal = new Calculo_Mehta();
String valueDouble= Double.toString(agua_material_cimenticio_mehta(cal));
textview.setText(valueDouble);
```

**Obs.:** Você deve definir todos os valores dentro de `Calculo_Mehta` para que funcione corretamente.

Comment: Entendi!! Essa parte de colocar o double resistencia_concreto dentro do parenteses do método eu já tinha pensado, mas e com relação aos outros? Essa é minha duvida maior, pois os outros tem mais de uma variável.

Comment: Com relação ao text view, está retornando direitinho:

`double massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_mehta = Calculo_Mehta.volume_agua_mehta()*volume; //Massa água
                        String stg_resultado_agua_mehta = Double.toString(massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_mehta);
                        resultado_agua.setText(stg_resultado_agua_mehta);`

Comment: Eu estou retornando corretamente as variáveis para as textviews, tanto que volume_agua_mehta() aparece na textview. Se as outras não aparecem, é porque está ocorrendo um erro na parte do public mesmo. Sacou?!?! Ai estou querendo entender essa parte.

Comment: @AnaWaldila fiz uma alteração na resposta, veja. Uma coisa que você tem que observar é como você está definindo os valores dentro da Classe Calculo_Mehta. Se estiver tudo ok, o método de retorno deve funcionar corretamente.

Comment: @AnaWaldila na verdade fica difícil reproduzir seu erro porque não está disponibilizando todo o código. Então por isso estou pedindo para conferir se está definindo corretamente todos os valores. Se por um acaso algum método estiver retornando erro, vai realmente dar pau.

Comment: Coloquei mais o conteudo do meu código, não todo porque tem muito mais coisa. Voce consegue identificar o erro? Já olhei tanto pra isso dai que não vejo mais nada.

Comment: @AnaWaldila Verificou se é questão de lógica? Talvez esteja fazendo um calculo que não seja possível.

Comment: @AnaWaldila segundo método eu coloquei um valor fixo no lugar da variável e retornou normalmente: `return (130 * 5 + 0.319 * Math.log(32) - 3.332) * 23;`

Comment: @AnaWaldila Mais uma vez vou ressaltar, você tem que verificar no log se suas variáveis estão sendo atribuídas corretamente.

Comment: @AnaWaldila percebi ali também que quando você muda de uma tela pra outra, você está passando somente 2 variáveis através do extra, no entanto o seu método possui 4 métodos para 4 variáveis diferente. Dê mais uma pensada, mais tarde eu volto ´pra te ajudar.

Comment: Sim sim, eu coloquei parte do código, não coloquei todo porque ele é um pouco extenso, mas as outras variáveis eu passei sim.